# How do I start fresh with ecryptfs

Tags: ecryptfs

This is my first attempt to use ecryptfs. What am I doing wrong?

```
mkdir mydir
sudo mount -t ecryptfs  ./mydir  ./mydir
Passphrase: 
Select cipher: 
 1) aes: blocksize = 16; min keysize = 16; max keysize = 32
 2) blowfish: blocksize = 8; min keysize = 16; max keysize = 56
 3) des3_ede: blocksize = 8; min keysize = 24; max keysize = 24
 4) twofish: blocksize = 16; min keysize = 16; max keysize = 32
 5) cast6: blocksize = 16; min keysize = 16; max keysize = 32
 6) cast5: blocksize = 8; min keysize = 5; max keysize = 16
Selection [aes]: 
Select key bytes: 
 1) 16
 2) 32
 3) 24
Selection [16]: 
Enable plaintext passthrough (y/n) [n]: 
Enable filename encryption (y/n) [n]: 
Attempting to mount with the following options:
  ecryptfs_unlink_sigs
  ecryptfs_key_bytes=16
  ecryptfs_cipher=aes
  ecryptfs_sig=c64595108101311e
WARNING: Based on the contents of [/root/.ecryptfs/sig-cache.txt],
it looks like you have never mounted with this key 
before. This could mean that you have typed your 
passphrase wrong.
```

If I try to define a fresh password using this:

```
ecryptfs-rewrap-passphrase /home/$USER/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase
```

it wants the old one too!  I do not have an old password as this is my first try.

Comment: If you have lost the old one  then it's a fresh start, it's doing its job as exppected!

Comment: I have not lost the old one. I never had it. I have never used ecryptfs. I want to start using it for the first time.

Comment: `man -k ecryptfs` should show you about 24 `man` pages you should read, or at least glance at. `for i in $( man -k ecryptfs | cut "-d " -f1 ) ; do  man $i ; done` will show them to you.

Comment: I read the manual. No mention of how to flush out from ecryptfs passphrases, signatures or whatever rubbish that there might be. I simply want a fresh start as a new user.  And as I have never set it up or used it before it is very odd that there is any passphrase,  signature etc in there at all.